# Remove element by name/value from json object

Tags: jquery, json

How can I remove "window3" from below json object str

var json1 = {"panel0": {"window3":{"collapsed":false},"window0":{"collapsed":false}},"panel1": {"window2":{"collapsed":false},"window1":{"collapsed":false}},"floating":{},"orientation": "horizontal"};

Thank you.

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: Hi, I am using PHP - zend framework, for above object I am using jqwidget jqxdocking for drag n drop window. Above json object I got from exportlayout. pls advice

Comment: There is no such thing as a json object :)

Comment: You means, cannot I remove 'window3' from above example?

Answer (score 1):

In JSONiq it would be:

```
delete json $json1("panel0")("window3")
```

(see http://www.zorba-xquery.com/html/demo#KkcoASbF2krqvFgXSwf22RLQJgo= )

Comment: It is not working in jquery - i tried to run your line of code but I got error - 
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement [Break On This Error]  

delete json $json1("panel0")(key)  - I am using jquery, zend html

Comment: Ah, sorry about that, I was not aware it was about jQuery. I added the corresponding tag.

Comment: Hi, do you have any solution to my query? pls advice

Comment: Would the following answer help? Something like "delete json1.panel0.window3"? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-to-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object

Comment: I have tried with same, but it did not work for me :( I am now trying to fix it in other way.. i did some customization in my code and trying to fix it.but yes.. thanks for your response to my query.